# Are USERLANGUAGE and JSESSIONID cookies implicit?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, httpsession

As for the subject: Are USERLANGUAGE and  JSESSIONID cookies implicitly part of HttpServletRequest? Even without declaring any httpsession?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

         //   HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
            Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
            ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                 out.println(cookie.getName()+": "+ cookie.getValue());
            }
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
}
```

In the above code reported for example even though I do not declare any httpSession I get **USERLANGUAGE** and **JSESSIONID** as part of the Cookies array. Should not I have got `null` instead?

Comment: Once a cookie is set, it's sent with every subsequent request (to the same host and path). The browser can't know that you won't use the session in this particular request. It sends the cookie, that's all. USERLANGUAGE is not a "standard" Java EE cookie. Your application must have set it explicitely.

Comment: @JBNizet I actually have not set neither of the 2 cookies.. maybe it's intelliJ that automatically does it?

Comment: @JBNizet regarding JSESSIONID you are right.. opened it with another browser and it did not show up. However still the USERLANGUAGE was present.

Comment: IntelliJ is the tool you use to edit, compile, and maybe deploy code to the web server. It is irrelevant. USERLANGUAGE could be set by a framework you're using, or another application running on the same host.